# Issues with seeking in a multi source DES project with sources other than WMV VC-1

Tags: directshow

I have a piece of legacy software that is based on DirectShow Editing Services. It has a player which purpose is to merge a few segments of video files and render it as a DES preview on the form with EVR. 
It works perfectly well with one source or when all of the sources are WMV VC-1 files. However, when there is more than one `IAMTimelineSrc` added to the `IAMTimeline`, then if there are sources other than WMV VC-1, the preview simply hangs when I try to seek through the timeline. I’m not getting any error or anything, both audio and video rendering simply stops.

I create source in straightforward way:
First I create a new empty timeline node:
`IAMTimeline::CreateEmptyNode` with `TIMELINE_MAJOR_TYPE` as `Source` (4)
Then set the required source properties:

```
IAMTimelineObj::SetStartStop 

IAMTimelineSrc::SetMediaName

IAMTimelineSrc::SetMediaTimes
```

Then I render the IAMTimeline with IRenderEngine as:

```
IRenderEngine::SetTimelineObject

IRenderEngine::ConnectFrontEnd

IRenderEngine::GetFilterGraph
```

And for each group (I have 2, one group with video sources and one with audio sources)

```
IAMTimelineGroup::SetPreviewMode(true)

IRenderEngine::GetGroupOutputPin

ICaptureGraphBuilder2::RenderStream
```

And it all works perfectly as long as I use WMV VC-1 files as sources which are rendered as `WM ASF Reader -> WMVideo Decoder DMO`.
However, any other format, even DV-AVI that works fine in Movie Maker, that is supposedly using DES as well, causes sever issues with `IMediaSeeking::SetPositions`. I invoke `IMediaSeeking::SetPositions` with `dwCurrentFlags` as `AMSeekingSeekingFlags.AbsolutePositionin`, `0` `pStop`, and `dwStopFlags` as `AMSeekingSeekingFlags.NoPositioning`.

What can be causing such issues with seeking through DES preview? I can't believe that DES is only compatible with WMV VC-1, especially since Movie Maker clearly supports more formats than just WMV VC-1. What might I be missing?